# How can I rotate the thumbnail image inside a post/page on the fly, using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, rotation

Inside my wordpress template, in the LOOP, I am loading the thumbnail image.

How can I rotate it 90 degrees using php inside my template?

I would like to avoid doing this manually as there are many pages using the same template.

Thank you!

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
  <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-none d-md-block" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Comment: I tried like this
```
 <?php 
                 $filename = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )[0];
                    $degrees = 180;
                    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
                    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
                    imagejpeg($rotate);
  
                ?>
but the output is dark page with a broken image
```

Comment: More details on what specifically you are trying to do, or why you need to rotate would be useful. Because if the image just needs to display rotated, you might not need php, you could do it with css `transform: rotate(90deg);` and only apply that style in the posts/areas you need it rotated.

Comment: Basically, I am using the page thumbnail as the product image (picture of a wine bottle). On smaller screens and category pages I would like to display the image horizontally instead of vertically. I know I can do it with css, however that causes some difficulties with the positioning of the element. Having the source image in the right orientation would be cleaner. However I'm not sure how efficient it is, if it's even possible to do

Answer (score 1):

You can use css for your image

```
.your-image-class {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Or if you need really rotate your image in wordpress gallery use next function:

```
$image_editor = wp_get_image_editor( $path, $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to call the php file through img src tag

```
<?php

function getImagePath(){
   return $_GET["img"];
}
// File and rotation
$filename = getImagePath();
$degrees = -90;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=10800, pre-check=10800");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822,strtotime(" 2 day")));
// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);

// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
?>
```